Why I still cannot receive email from website?
Everything was okay at the start, but only after I click my web "send message", email send alert I haven't received the email from web and the page become error. HTTP ERROR 405
I had tried [Update Service], and it is working. I can receive the email from Emailjs but only cannot from the website.
Pls help me to find how is it happens and fix it. I need to receive the email from website and without error page.

Please, help us help you by providing more context to your problem.
